# How expensive is runtime image scaling in mobile AIR environments?

Tags: performance, mobile, air, runtime, image-scaling

My guess is that this is actually relatively expensive. I haven't profiled it just yet, but I'm looking for some insight.  If I'm scaling a large bitmap (433x396) to a size maybe 1/5 of the size at runtime, how much of a performance hit is it?  Especially in cases where it's repeated 4 or 5 times.  I'm not aware of if it really depends on the underlying system like Java does.  I'm trying to target different pixel densities,  and my goal would be to bundle a different set of assets based on device configuration via ant script to reduce the size of the application bundle.  I'm not looking directly for any workarounds, I just want some insight into understanding the performance cost of runtime scaling so I can make an informed decision.  Thanks to all in advance.